# Failed to run spark query in databricks notebook after storage configurations

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I already set up key vault scope in the notebooks and I established the connection to the storage account using the following steps:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type."+StorageAccountName+".dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type."+StorageAccountName+".dfs.core.windows.net","org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id."+StorageAccountName+".dfs.core.windows.net",clientId)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret."+StorageAccountName+".dfs.core.windows.net",clientSecret)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint."+StorageAccountName+".dfs.core.windows.net","https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantid/oauth2/token")
```

The values of "StorageAccountName", "clientId", "clientSecret" all come from key vault and I am able to get their value properly. In my storage account access control I also assigned the
Storage Blob Data Contributor role to my service principal.

After these configurations, I assigned a connection variable:

```
var apptable = "abfss://container@"+StorageAccountName+".dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/data"
```

If I run the following command, I am able to see the files in the blob storage

```
display(dbutils.fs.ls(apptable))
```

I am also able to check the schema:

```
var df = spark.read.format("delta").load(apptable)
df.printSchema()
```

but if I tried to run the following query:

```
var last_appt = spark.sql(s"""select max(updateddate) from apptable""").collect()(0).getTimestamp(0)
```

I got the error:

```
KeyProviderException: Failure to initialize configuration
Caused by: InvalidConfigurationValueException: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
```

I researched online and seems there are some issues in the spark configs. But if it failed to get access to the storage, how come the above display command is running well? What could be possibly missing in such scenario?

I have limited experience on databricks. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results and I configure same as mentioned above.**

Please follow below code:

> **Read spark dataframe `df`.**

```
var df = spark.read.format("delta").load(apptable)
```

Create temp table:

```
%scala

temp_table_name = "demtb"
df.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table_name)
```

Now, using below code. I got this output.

```
%scala

val aa= spark.sql("""select max(marks) from demtb""")
display(aa)
```

[image]

**Update:**

As mentioned, in below comment its working fine for me.

```
df1.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").option("path","/FileStore/dd/").option("overwriteschema","true").saveAsTable("app")
```

[image]

And also, you can try this syntax for configuring azure gen2.As per requirement you can change file format. For demo I'm using csv.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net","Access_key")
```

> **Scala**

```
%scala

val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("abfss://pool@vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net/")
display(df1)
```

[image]

> **Python**

```
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("abfss://pool@vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net/")
    display(df1)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the second step and it said 'error: not found: value temp_table_name
temp_table_name = "demtb"', also, I tried to save the df immediately like this it failed with the same key vault exception error as I described above. Does it work on your side?
```
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").option("path",s"$outputPath/app").option("overwriteschema","true").saveAsTable("app")
```

Comment: I found that even I hardcode the those values when running those spark.conf.set() commands, e.g. explicitly paste the clientid and client secret, it is still not working.

Comment: Hey I checked the driver log, it looks like when it wants to initialize the file system, it is still using the old config instead of the latest value from the key vault, e.g., the StorageAccountName's latest version is 'test', the old version is 'temp', when I print the value, I can see I am using 'test', but in the driver log it shows initializing with 'temp'

Comment: Do you know how to change the file system that the local drive to initialize? I get confused about why it is always initializing with the wrong/legacy configs

Comment: hi @Vanderwood, please check the above update and also follow this [link1](https://i.imgur.com/snyL2wX.png) for creating temp table.